# Why are some tags in Visual studio code red?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

My VS code is coloring SOME tags in red but I cant figure out why. The image is self explanatory. The code runs with no errors.

[image]

Comment: Seems like your second `<link>` tag is not closed.

Comment: guitartab.css link is missing a close. It looks like it’s unhappy with an empty svg (demo1). Maybe other errors.

Comment: I fixed the css tag and also if I comment out the svg tags, everything cleans up. Does it not like the svg tags ?

Comment: Also the svg tags are populated with D3.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when tags are deprecated, visual studio will highlight them in red. this tells the programmer that such functions are no longer useful in the new era of web development.